Performant Arrays of Objects in Python
I am trying to create a sparse data structure in Python but am having a difficult time putting together the right set of primitives to get the job done.
The data structure is a page-table, not unlike ones you find in modern computer architectures. The idea is that the data structure is sparse until it gets filled out. To implement this, I need to have a performant want to manage an array of arrays.
In my case, I want to map out which IP addresses are encountered during a given operation. Adding the ip address to the data structure looks like this:
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        p = IpTable._parts(key)

        map = self._map
        for idx in p[0:3]:
            if type(np.ndarray) != type(map[idx]):
                map[idx] = np.zeros(256)
            map = map[idx]
        map[p[3]] = value

where _parts() takes e.g. 192.168.0.1 and produces [192, 168, 0, 1]. I thought maybe I could use NumPy here (or even SciPy's sparse arrays) but I think my conclusion is that those are primarily targeting matrix math operations; they did not like it when I set values to anything other than integers. In my case I need to set element values to be subsequent arrays.
One entry in the data structure might looks like so:
A[192] = B
B[168] = C
C[0] =   D
D[1] =   value

Am I missing something with NumPy/SciPy or are these not the right tools for the job? I was hoping to make this reasonably performant, otherwise I know I could just use objects directly like:
A['192.168.0.1'] = value

But considering that likely uses hash tables internally, maybe it's not a terrible choice either.

This sounds like a job for just an ordinary dict. Did you have some particular reason not to go with a dict?

I fail to see why you are trying to build something when a simple dict could apparently be a valid solution. You might want to clarify what data you want to store and how you intend to use it, and so what performance problem exactly you would have.

@ThierryLathuille I said as much towards the end of the post. Maybe I'll just use dict. This was partially academic, but I think dict might just a do the job well enough.

An object dtype array can hold anything, just as a list. It's no more 'performant', but does allow for multidimensional indexing.

This
A[192] = B
B[168] = C
C[0] =   D
D[1] =   value

suggest you actually wants 4D array, this can be done following way
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((256,256,256,256), dtype='uint8')
arr[192][168][0][1] = 123
print(arr[192][168][0][1])  # 123

Explanation: I create 256x256x256x256 array for holding integers from range 0 to 255. You need to select possible smallest data type which is enough for your purpose if you want to be performant w.r.t memory. Note: this is not sparse.
